# delete dynamic table with index

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I created a dynamic table using html and javascript.

```
$('#btn-add-share').click(function (){
    if($('#ddlDepartment option:selected').val() == 0){
            alert('Please Input Department');
    }else{
            var lastArray = filemanager.data.length;
            var currId = lastArray;
            currId++;
        filemanager.data.push({
            id: currId,
            department:$('#ddlDepartment').val(),
            city:$('#ddlCity').val(),
            province:$('#ddlProvince').val(),
            position:$('#ddlPosition').val(),
        });
        $('#sharedFolder tbody').append("<tr><td>"+currId+"</td><td>"+$('#ddlDepartment option:selected').text()+"</td><td>"+$('#ddlProvince option:selected').text()+"</td><td>"+$('#ddlCity option:selected').text()+"</td><td>"+$('#ddlPosition option:selected').text()+"</td> <td class='text-center'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete' id='btn-delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Del</button></td></tr>");
    }
}
);
```

So every time row is added, the input will be passed into filemanager.data. The problem is, how to delete specific row and pop data by index when I want to remove row? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the `jQuery#eq(index)` method to select the nth table row and remove it.
- Use [`Array#splice(index, deleteCount)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the nth element from your `filemanager.data` array (which I assume is an array given your call to `filemanager.data.push`).
- `splice` also returns an array containing the deleted elements, and since you only deleted a single element, so you can get the original data back by accessing index zero on that array.

```js
function popData (index) {
    $('#sharedFolder tr').eq(index).remove()
    return filemanager.data.splice(index, 1)[0]
}
```